# Change CSS value when page has loaded on all EXCEPT first instance

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following piece of code do change the value of a division once the page has loaded but I was wondering if it would be possible to amend it to change the value of all of the divisions with that class with the **exception of the first one**.

```
jQuery('#accordion div.pane').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to select all but the first:

```
jQuery('#accordion div.pane:gt(0)').css('display', 'none');
```

or the less concise "notty firsty":

```
jQuery('#accordion div.pane:not(:first)').css('display', 'none');
```

and why not use hide instead of setting the style:

```
jQuery('#accordion div.pane:gt(0)').hide();
```

For better performance (and a concise solution), you might consider using JavaScript's [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice), which works on jQuery objects since they are *arrayish*:

```
jQuery('div').slice(1).hide();
```

Comment: A note on things like `:first` from the docs: "Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first")."

Comment: Would there be a way to bind this to a link? for example if a user clicked on option 2 from an external page in the menu it could go to the page and open up the second pane?

Comment: @Vince Pettit - I think you would be better off asking that as another question, since it depends on your specific requirements, and more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#accordion div.pane').not(':first').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give your first element a distinguishing ID or class, and use the jQuery not selector:

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector